# Direct summand if prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$k$ is a field of prime characteristic $p$, $G$ is a finite group and $\Omega$ a $G$-set, with $G$ acting transitively on $\Omega$. Consider

$$M=k.\left(\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}b_\omega\right)$$

Apparently $M$ is a direct summand of $k\Omega$ iff $p$ and $|\Omega|$ are coprime.

How can I prove that? If they're coprime, that implies that $p$ doesn't divide $|\Omega|$, given that $p$ is prime. So then $k\Omega$ has an element of order $p$. But there I get stuck. How can I prove that being a direct summand is true only when the numbers are coprime?

Comment: The definition of $M$ is not clear: what does $b_{\omega}$ denote? Moreover, what do you mean by "$|\Omega|$ has an element of order $p$"? $|\Omega|$ is a number, not a group.

Comment: You mean if they are not coprime then $p$ divides $|\Omega|$.

Comment: I eant $k\Omega$ has an element of order $p$ - question edited to match. Yes, if they're coprime that implies p doesn't divide $|\Omega|$ - question updated. The question doesn't say what b_w is.

Comment: I suggest the $b_\omega$ form the basis of the vector space $k\Omega$, with the action $(b_\omega)g=b_{\omega g}$.

Comment: If you are asking a question it is your responsibility to explain the meaning of the notation in that question. And if you do not know what it means yourself, then you have no hope at all of answering the question. What did you mean by $k\Omega$ has an element of order $p$?

Comment: From looking through the notes, $b_w$ is indeed used as a basis for $k\Omega$. I believe I've found the answer to this question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem.